# jQuery : How to Select .parent .prev Correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

usually I use this jquery :

```
$( ".product_imgfiles a" ).click(function(event) {
   $( this ).parent( "div" ).remove();
});
```

but, it only works on document ready, not with new appended elements. then I change into this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function() {
   $( this ).parent( "div" ).remove();
});
```

but, on the second one, my code doesn't remove the div. I read some post in this forum and modified into some combinations :

```
$( this ).prev().parent( "div" ).remove();
$( this ).parent( "div" ).prev().remove();
$( this ).parent().prev( "div" ).remove();
```

none of them sucessfully remove the parent div of current `.product_imgfiles`. how to make selection correctly in this case?

update : HTML structure

```
<div id="product_imgfiles_container" class="row">
    <?
        if (isset ($product_imgfiles)) {
            for ($i=2; $i<($num_product_imgfiles+2); $i++) {
                echo '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2" style="padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">
                        <div class="thumbnail product_imgfiles">
                            <img src="'. $directory . $product_imgfiles[$i] .'" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                            <a href=""><span><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> hapus</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: show your html structure.

Comment: do you append elements to same div or new divs?

Comment: It is quiet _impossible_ to suggest a valid selector without understanding `DOM structure`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla : hi bro, check my update above.

Comment: @RayonDabre : please check my DOM structure above. just updated.

Comment: 1. You can use event delegating. Attach event listener to the container where all items goes and then delegate clicks.  2. Attach listeners to every item when adding them

Comment: Maybe you could try console.log(this); inside your click event  and check what it exactly pointing to ?

Comment: isn't `.parent( "div" )` in the first code snippet refering to .product_imgfiles div?

Comment: @RobertHanson check my answer, You used a anchor tag with href="" and that will refresh your page on click and that is why you see no div removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it

```
$(document).on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function() {
   $( this ).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

You need to delete the parent of `product_imgfiles` div.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` inside the event handler refers to the `<a>` element that is clicked. To get the closest ancestor, use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(this)                           // Clicked anchor element
    .closest('.product_imgfiles') // Get closest ancestor having that class
    .parent()                     // Get direct parent
    .remove();                    // Remove from DOM
```

---

I'll suggest to add a class to the parent of the `.product_imgfiles` element and use that to remove the element from DOM.

**HTML:**

```
echo '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 productContainer"> ...
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Add this class
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(this).closest('.productContainer').remove();
```

Comment: this will remove the col-xs-4 div

Comment: @madalinivascu Isn't that what OP wants

Comment: @madalinivascu that is what OP is looking for `none of them sucessfully remove the parent div of current .product_imgfiles`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a anchor tag with `href=""` so that will refresh your page on click and that is why you are seeing no div removed. Just add the `e.preventDefault();` before your .remove() call like below :

```
$(document).on("click", ".product_imgfiles a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( this ).parent().parent().remove();// remove the div containing the div.product_imgfiles
});
```